# FastAPI requests throwing TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, fastapi

I am presently trying to get json data from a FastAPI endpoint using request, but I keep getting this error for all three queries:

```
TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable
```

here is the code:

```py
@app.post('/')
async def send_mail(req: Request):
    subject = req.json['subject']
    reply_to = req.json['recipient']
    body = req.json['message']
    message.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
    text = message.as_string()
    server.sendmail(from_addr, to_addrs, text)
    return {'message' : 'Thanks for contacting us, we will reach out shortly.'}
```

I  find this strange cos this works when I used Flask. I wonder why this is different.

Answer (score 1):

The `Request` object in **FastAPI** comes from **Starlette**, this object only has a `.json()` function rather than a dictionary, you can get the same result by storing the `json` call's result first and using that instead. You can read up on this over at [Starlette's `Request` documentation](https://www.starlette.io/requests/#body).

I would, however, highly suggest following the **FastAPI** tutorials on a much cleaner way of handling objects sent through a request to your backend, you can read up on that over at [FastAPI's `Request Body` documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body/).